# Postgresql - "ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xf0 0x9f 0x98 0x84 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252""

Tags: django, postgresql

So I was querying on my Heroku server with this query

```
// Command to get into postgres
heroku pg:psql
// Query
SELECT * FROM cheers_post;
```

then I get this error

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xf0 0x9f 0x98 0x84 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

I don't know what character `0xf0 0x9f 0x98 0x84` is in UTF8. This error isn't super explicit so I'm not really sure what the issue is or how to fix it. Anyone experience this? Something interesting is when I query the `cheers_post` table via a Django API endpoint it returns `Post.DoesNotExist` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is as explicit as possible: that character (, UNICODE code point 1F604) cannot be represented in the client encoding you chose.

The solution is straightforward: choose a different client encoding in which the character can be represented, for example `UTF8`. If that is not an option, don't fetch that value from the database.

Comment: so does this mean that someone tried to fill one of the attributes field with a character that can only be represented in `UTF8`, but because it's set for `WIN1252` I'm getting this error? How do I changed the "client encoding?"

Comment: Someone stored an emoticon in the database. That cannot be represented in Windows single-byte encodings. I have no idea how you should change the client encoding in your application - that is rather application (or driver) specific.

Comment: I was under the impression that postgres automatically supports UTF8. Do you know why it defaulted to `WIN1252`? I have another table where I store emoticons and that table doesn't throw an error.

Comment: PostgreSQL supports UTF-8 (else you couldn't have that character), but you specified the WIN1252 client encoding. That is your problem.

Comment: hmm interesting. Thanks for this I posted a separate question asking how to change the client encoding. I'm not really that familiar with this aspect of Django. Or is this a postgresql or Heroku thing?